# Taylor series expansion of $\frac{1}{1+j-z^2}$

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion

I know to manipulate $\frac{1}{1+j-z^2}$ to get a result in the form of $\frac{1}{1-z}$. However, I have only managed to get to $\frac{1}{(-z+1)(-z-1)+j}$. I'm not sure how to manipulate this further

Comment: Try the substitution $u = z^2/(1+j)$

Comment: thank you, the substitution worked

Comment: You welcome, nice having helped you